# finding the number of occurrences for a specific char using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, return, try-catch

This code below is part of a program, that will find the number of occurrences of the input character in a text file

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    [...]
    java.io.File file1=new java.io.File(dirPath1);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
    System.out.println("  return "+rec(sc.next().charAt(0),fis));
}



public static int rec (char ch, FileInputStream fis)throws IOException{
    char current=0;
    if(fis.available()==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(fis.read()!=-1){
        current = (char) fis.read();
    }

    if(current==ch) {     
        return 1+rec(ch,fis);
    }else
        return rec(ch,fis);
    }
}
```

The problem is:

If the file has one character, and `ch`=that one character. it returns 0, when I traced the code I found that it doesn't enter `if(current==ch)`.  Although, they are the same char.

if there is more than on character,strings some of them-the matches chars- will enter `if block` and others won't.
How can I fix this ?

Is there another way to find the number of occurrences **recursively** ?

another question: should I use `try` and `catch` in  `rec` method to catch `IOException` ?

Thanks in advance

P.S. this program is from assignment,I have to use recursion and compare it with iteration.

Comment: Instead of reading byte by byte, you could try using `BufferedReader betterFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PATH));` . This way you can directly read chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you call fis.read() twice first one read first character and second one read nothing

this is your answer

```
public static int rec(char ch, FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {

    char current = 0;
    if (fis.available() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int read = fis.read();
    if (read != -1) {
        current = (char) read;
    }

    if (current == ch) {

        return 1 + rec(ch, fis);
    }

    else
        return rec(ch, fis);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be as follows:

1. Read the whole text file into a java.lang.String
2. Then use the library Apache Commons Lang and use this method for counting the occurrences:
   http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 0):

You should use FileReader to read chars from text file.

`Reader reader = new FileReader("MyFile.txt");`

I think using `while ((i=reader.read()) != -1)` is a better approach instead of three `if` and an `else`.

So you can achieve this with fewer lines of code:

```
public static int rec (char ch, Reader reader)throws IOException{
    char current=0;
    int i; 
    while ((i=reader.read()) != -1) {
        current = (char) i;
        if(current==ch) {     
            return 1+rec(ch,reader);
        }else
            return rec(ch,reader);
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

I think there is no need to use try and catch in  rec method to catch IOException. I have used it here:

```
    try {
        Reader reader = new FileReader("MyFile.txt");
        System.out.println("  return " + rec('a', reader));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.